# ANSI C - Functions as Arguments to Other Functions

Tags: c, function-pointers, ansi-c

I've got these prototypes:

```
int *my_func(int x, void (*other_func)(int a, int b));

int func2(int val1, int val2);
```

Assume there is a function written that matches it.

If I want to actually call my_func, how would I do it? I've tried the following with no luck:

```
my_func(1,func2);
```

Here's the error:

```
warning: passing argument 2 of ‘my_func’ from incompatible pointer type
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's because the function prototypes don't match:

```
void (*other_func)(void *a, int *b)
```

is not the same as:

```
int func2(int val1, int val2);
```

One takes a `void*` and `int*`, while the other takes two `int`s.

EDIT:

Also, the return type doesn't match.

EDIT 2:

**Since you've fixed both errors, this answer is out of context.** I just tested it with these two fixes, and it compiles:

```
int *my_func(int x, void (*other_func)(int a, int b)){
    return 0;
}
void func2(int val1, int val2){
    printf("blah");
}


int main(){
    my_func(1,func2);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Oops, typo. Updated. That shouldn't be the issue still.

Comment: The return type also doesn't match.

Comment: Why the downvote? If there was something wrong with my answer, I'd like to hear it. EDIT: Well, does it still fail? Since you've fixed both things, my answer is out of context now.

Answer (score 2):

Your original code had `void*` for the first argument of the passed function and a return type of `int`, and that was causing your issue:

```
int *my_func(int x, void (*other_func)(void * a, int b)) { return 0;}
int func2(int val1, int val2) {}
int main (void) {
    my_func (42, func2);
    return 0;
}
```

With the following edits, changing it to an `int` and returning `void`, there *is* no issue:

```
int my_func(int x, void (*other_func)(int a, int b)) { return 0;}
void func2(int val1, int val2) {}
int main (void) {
    my_func (42, func2);
    return 0;
}
```

Compiling the former gives you:

```
warning: passing argument 2 of 'my_func' from incompatible pointer type
```

Compiling the latter gives you no errors or warnings and the object file is created fine.

Answer (score 0):

Often[(1)](http://www.devx.com/tips/Tip/13829)[(2)](http://c-faq.com/~scs/cclass/int/sx10a.html) we use "typedef" to make sure that the kind of function we have matches the kind of function expected as an argument to the other function.

```
typedef void (*pt2Func)(void *, int *);

int *my_func(int x, pt2Func other_func);

pt2Func func3;

int main(void){
    my_func(1,func3);
}
```

which means the same thing as

```
int *my_func(int x, void (*other_func)(void *a, int *b));

void func3(void *val1, int *val2);

int main(void){
    my_func(1,func3);
}
```

Comment: In oder to make this work, you have to use `typedef void func_t(void *, int *);` and then `int *my_func(int x, func_t * other_func);`. Otherwise, the `pt2Func func3;` will fail as you want to declare a code object, not a pointer.